# Is it possible to show bootstrap model for adding new columns in ag-grid by adding additional header option?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, ag-grid

Is it possible to add columns in ag-grid? there are some default options (pin column, Autosize etc.) available and I like to add a new column which is based on existing columns. I like to show bootstrap model for entering columns and ag-grid does not use bootstrap and I am not sure how can I show model form when user clicks on additional column menu option on header row.

Comment: GridCore.prototype.showFormulaPanel = function (name) {
         if (name) {
             $('#name').model('show');//$(name).model('show');
         }
     };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ag-grid config provides ways to add context menu and header menu. 
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-callbacks/index.php
I was able to use the getMainMenuItems for header context menu.